# C++: casting class struct in a namespace to unsigned char *

Tags: c++, casting, namespaces

I have a problem in casting. I have always gotten expected unqualified-id before reinterpret_cast which I think would be problem of namespace

My code is as such

```
namespace A{
   class MsgA{
    public:
       typedef struct{         
            int b;
            short c;    
       }struct_d

       struct_d retrieveStruct(void);
     };
 }

// in another file , using no namespace, 
 
 void nonamespace::get(unsigned char *buffer)
 {
     //........ some lined of code
     buffer = std::reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(ptr_of_MsgA_object->retrieveStruct());
  }
```

I run into above compiler problems whenever I tried to cast it but it compiles fine if I just retrieve the struct, something like

```
   ptr_of_MsgA_object->retrieveStruct();
```

My suspicion is that it maybe the namespace causing the problem. Hence this question

Wonder how do we operate on struct  on another namespace?

Regards

Comment: Change `std::reinterpret_cast` to `reinterpret_cast`. reinterpret_cast is a keyword, it does not exist in any namespace.

Comment: You could have checked your suspicion about the namespace being the culprit by trying something simpler, like `std::reinterpret_cast<char*>(0)`, and discovering that it isn't.

Comment: @john no luck there.  The error is changed to invalid cast from  type A::MsgA::struct_d to type unsigned char *

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for the suggestion ... but by being able to do the above would meant what? I mean the next step

Comment: @user1538798 Since it fails in exactly the same way, you can reasonably conclude that your namespaces and structs have nothing to do with this particular problem. Then you might consider reading about `reinterpret_cast` and noticing that it's not in the `std` namespace. (That you can't cast a struct to a pointer by any means is another problem, but it's not this problem.)

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a few things wrong with this code, the assignment to a pointer parameter being one of them. I suspect that even when working that does not do what you think it does.

However in an effort to get you past your compilation errors I would suggest this

```
namespace A {
    class MsgA {
    public:
       struct struct_d { // no typedef, instead C++ style definition
            int b;
            short c;    
       };

       struct_d& retrieveStruct(void); // returns a reference, this is important
     };
}

// in another file , using no namespace, 
 
void nonamespace::get(unsigned char *buffer)
{
     //........ some lines of code
     buffer = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(
         &ptr_of_MsgA_object->retrieveStruct() // use & to get pointer
     );
}
```

Now at least you can progress. As I said I suspect a few other issues, around object lifetimes, and how pointers work. But those are typical newbie issues.

In particular I suspect that `get` should be rewritten like this

```
unsigned char *nonamespace::get()
{
     //........ some lines of code
     return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(
         &ptr_of_MsgA_object->retrieveStruct() // use & to get pointer
     );
}
```

Or just possibly like this

```
void nonamespace::get()
{
     //........ some lines of code
     unsigned char* buffer = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(
         &ptr_of_MsgA_object->retrieveStruct() // use & to get pointer
     );
}
```

The version you have does not make a lot of sense, but I can't say for sure that it is wrong.